# Remove Items form Array logic - present tense and present continuous tense

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Sort by count of letters.Check for words that begin with the same letter.Check if a word is completely present in another word.when both begin with the same letter.If it is completely present.show only the first word and ignore the second word

```
var arraylist = ["running", "walking", "standing", "writing", "waiting", "sleeping", "reading", "washing", "sitting", "riding", "shopping", "singing", "painting", "watching", "swimming", "pulling", "smoking", "pushing", "drinking", "dancing", "cooking", "crying   ", "eating", "smiling","run", "walk", "push", "cook", "cry", "eat"];
```

Expecting Output using javascript/jquery:

I need to remove these words:  running, walking, pushing, cooking, crying, eating.

```
var arrayList = ["run", "walk", "standing", "writing", "waiting", "sleeping", "reading", "washing", "sitting", "riding", "shopping", "singing", "painting", "watching", "swimming", "pulling", "smoking", "push", "drinking", "dancing", "cook", "cry", "eat", "smiling","run", "walk", "push", "cook", "cry", "eat"];
```

Comment: Remove might not be the right term. It seems you just want to "replace" them.

Comment: follow the link. my formating was blown when the page pushed my reply into comment due to shortness

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/remove-specific-element-from-an-array

Comment: @user3154108 whaaaat?

Comment: @GeorgeGarchagudashvili It appears to have been automatically converted to a comment from an answer.

Comment: It seems it is not as simple as you think @user3154108. For example what if the word is 'smile' ? smile can not be found within smiling. Levenshtein distance algo will have to be used?

Comment: No need to remove manually.  need to check the every array(words) with other arrays(words). need to remove 2nd words.  eg) run and running are available in two arrays. the output should be run.

Comment: Ah, I seem to have missed the point of the question if it is about a specific algorithm

Comment: [This might helpful](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/133778/how-can-i-extract-words-from-a-sentence-and-determine-what-part-of-speech-each-i)

Answer (score 1):

for the case mentioned by @Grimbode
From OP

> Check if a word is completely present in another word

So *smile* not **completely present** in *smiling*

So this solution might be helpful

```
function filter(arr) {
  arr.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.length - b.length;
  })
  return arr.reduce(function(acc, el) {
    if (!acc.some(function(e) {
      return el.startsWith(e);
    })) {
      acc.push(el);
    }
    return acc;
  }, []);
}
```

**NOTE:** Polyfill for old browser from [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith#Polyfill)

```
if (!String.prototype.startsWith) {
    String.prototype.startsWith = function(searchString, position) {
        position = position || 0;
        return this.lastIndexOf(searchString, position) === position;
    };
}
```

```js
if (!String.prototype.startsWith) {
    String.prototype.startsWith = function(searchString, position) {
        position = position || 0;
        return this.lastIndexOf(searchString, position) === position;
    };
}

var arraylist = ["running", "walking", "standing", "writing", "waiting", "sleeping", "reading", "washing", "sitting", "riding", "shopping", "singing", "painting", "watching", "swimming", "pulling", "smoking", "pushing", "drinking", "dancing", "cooking", "crying   ", "eating", "smiling", "run", "walk", "push", "cook", "cry", "eat"];

function filter(arr) {
  arr.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.length - b.length;
  })
  return arr.reduce(function(acc, el) {
    if (!acc.some(function(e) {
      return el.startsWith(e);
    })) {
      acc.push(el);
    }
    return acc;
  }, []);
}
document.getElementById('before').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(arraylist);

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(filter(arraylist));
```

```html
<div><span>initial array:</span><span id="before"></span>
  <div>
    <div><span>result array:</span><span id="result"></span>
      <div>
```

Comment: The code not working. check it.

Comment: getting error in  this line :   return el.startsWith(el);

Comment: @RSKMR ohh, what browser you use?

Comment: Browser -  (chrome Version 38)

Comment: @RSKMR you right: [startsWith](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith), available in Chrome 41

Comment: @RSKMR try updated answer: adding polyfill for `startsWith`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75918/discussion-between-rskmr-and-grundy).

Answer (score 0):

Check this. Although this will not work in the case mentioned by @Grimbode

```js
var sentence = "Did Marying go to the store today?";
var arraylist = ["running", "walking", "standing", "writing", "waiting", "sleeping", "reading", "washing", "sitting", "riding", "shopping", "singing", "painting", "watching", "swimming", "pulling", "smoking", "pushing", "drinking", "dancing", "cooking", "crying   ", "eating", "smiling","run", "walk", "push", "cook", "cry", "eat"];


function myFunction() {
    $.each(arraylist, function(index,item){
       $.each(arraylist,function(indexInner, item1){
           if( index != indexInner && item1 && item && item1.substring(0,(item.length)) == item){  
             arraylist[indexInner] = arraylist[index];
             arraylist[index] = false;
           }
       });
    });
    arraylist = cleanArray(arraylist);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = arraylist;
}


function cleanArray(actual){
  var newArray = new Array();
  for(var i = 0; i<actual.length; i++){
      if (actual[i]){
        newArray.push(actual[i]);
    }
  }
  return newArray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Click the button to add elements to the array.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Its looks good. but its possible to work in the case mentioned by @Grimbode ?

Comment: @RSKMR I think if you use Levenshtein distance algo then 'smiling' can be replaced by 'smile'. But I think this won't resolve your actual target."replace present continuous form to present form" For example Lavenshtein distance algorithm can't replace 'lying' to 'lie'.